# $_POST not working in php while

Tags: php, mysql

Please check my code bellow and tell me what’s wrong I am doing here. I want to get echo "Submitted successfully"; message when “submit” is pressed but for some reason $_POST not passing anything.

```
$qu1 = mysql_query("SELECT adr_asin_link, adr_email, req_asin FROM work");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qu1)) {
  echo '<form action="" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "Submitted successfully";
  }

echo $adr_asin_link = $row['adr_asin_link']."<br>";
echo $req_asin = $row['req_asin']." Required asin"."<br>";

}
```

Comment: Remove `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ... }` inside the while loop. Just put it outside. You cannot simply check if a button is submitted if you don't click it and while the fetching is occuring.

Answer (score 6):

For submit you need to specify `name`, in your case:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```